# How do you display content of multiple edit text fields to one text view?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have been trying to figure out how to add many `EditText` values together and display the output to one `TextView`.

To be more specific:

I am having the user enter a number in each `EditText` field and need to display the total result. There are about 14 `EditText` fields and one `TextView`.

Comment: [Look for String Operations in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: For reference, do you want to add the values together, or combine them into 1 giant string?

Comment: I want to add all the values together and display the results. Like if the user enters 12 (in one EditText), 3 (in another EditText), and 8 (in another one) then the TextView should display 23.

Comment: @DrRoland I just posted solution for this please try with that.

Comment: Thanks @PratikSharma, I'm gonna try it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlsUsername);
etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlsPassword);
String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
String text = username + " " + password;
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText (text);
```

Just add as many Edit texts as you want.

if you want to sum the result of all textviews then you will need to get the integer values of the string in the textview by doing this:

```
numone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numone);
numtwo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numtwo);
String numonestring = numone.getText().toString();
String numtwostring = numtwo.getText().toString();
int one = Integer.valueOf(numonestring);
int two = Integer.valueOf(numtwostring );
int sum = one + two;
tv.setText (sum.toString());
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Get the text from each EditText, and add the values together. Then display the resulting string to the TextView. The following pseudo-code should show you how to start.

The key thing with using this bit of code is to populate `tv` and `textboxes`. Also, if your numbers are floating point, you will need to change the type of total and the parsing of it.

```
ArrayList<EditText> textboxes;
TextView tv;
int total=0
for (edit:textboxes)
{
    total+=Integer.parseInt(edit.getText());
}
tv.setText(text.toString());
```

Comment: Ah I see! I don't know why I didn't think of using an ArrayList haha, I'll give this a go and see what I get, thank you!

Comment: I may be wrong but from the keywords *numbers* and *total* I think that @DrRoland wants a sum of all numbers contained in all `EditText` fields.

Comment: You are right about what I want, I am checking now to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mRlayout1);
    int total = calculate(rl);
    yourTextView.setText(""+total);
```

Declare this method :

```
       // Method called for calculation   
        public int calculate(RelativeLayout layout) {
            int totalval = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
                Class<? extends View> c = v.getClass();
                if (c == EditText.class) {
                    EditText et = (EditText) v;
                    totalval += Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());                                          
                } 
            }
            return totalval;
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused, what is the mRlayout1?

Comment: It is showing some errors, one error is that public int calculate(RelativeLayout layout) is not able to be a method? Where do I put the method and the code that you put above that method?

Comment: @DrRoland this method will be outside block of oncreate method. And you can call above 3 lines from the oncreate method.

Comment: Ok I have the calculation method with no errors, but how do I make it so when I press a button a separate TextView displays the total of the numbers entered in the EditText fields?

Comment: @DrRoland call first 3 lines onClick of button. You also need to declare `yourTextView` before using it.

Comment: Thanks! A combination of Pratik Sharma code and @EmilAdj code worked perfectly, thank you guys very much!